# Python finding exact string in .html file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a .html file which gets dynamically filled depending on what actions are taken in the program, however I am having an issue when searching for an exact string, the issue is that although I know the file is not blank, the loop doesn't return anything and thinks its blank.

I have searched and read many other SO questions and tried many of them, including `'blah' in line`, `re.findall`, and `with open()` all the time they return only blank, I'm thinking I need HTML parsing or similar? 
Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

```
f = open(outApp + '_report.html', 'r+')
for line in f:
   #check the for loop works
   self.progressBox.AppendText(line)
   if 'mystring' in line:
       #do stuff
```

The string I wish to find is `My country` which is wrapped in h2 tags

Comment: `r+`, why do you write `r+`?

Comment: because i want to write to the file if 'mystring' is not found

Comment: then afaik it should be `r+w` or something like that.

Comment: I was going on what I found here: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python. `‘r+’ – Special read and write mode, which is used to handle both actions when working with a file`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `r+` is correct for opening a file read/write without truncating (text mode). `r+w` is not a valid mode.

Comment: Does `os.path.exists(outApp + '_report.html')` return `True`?

Comment: seems like you iterate over a file while you modify it. is it true?

Comment: @GalDreiman yes, it seems so, accidentally - so I'm guessing I'd need to iterate through the whole file first to find my string, and then take appropriate action. glibdud - yes thats True

Comment: @PShaw - I think this is the solution. BTW, you might want to take at a Python Common Pitfall: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/949/changing-the-sequence-you-are-iterating-over#t=201701301409334274444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely shouldn't be done without special HTML parser.

Google about any python HTML parser you want. For basic usage they are all easy. For example `lxml`. In pseudo-code your task would be:

```
from some_cool_lib import SomeCoolHTMLParser
parser = SomeCoolHTMLParser()
doc = parser.parse(path_to_my_html_file)
h2_elements = doc.findall('h2')
for h2 in h2_elements:
   if h2.text == 'My country':
      # do stuff
```